# Fake server with sinon and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, sinon

I used the example here (https://gist.github.com/cjohansen/739589) to create a test case with Jasmine and sinon. This test case works fine until I add a timeout property to the ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/something",
    timeout:3000, // <--
    success: callbacks[0]
});
```

Then Jasmine outputs the following error when executing "server.respond()":

> Uncaught TypeError: Fake XHR onreadystatechange handler threw exception: Illegal invocation

I start the tests from the file:

> jasmine-2_0\spec\runner.html

Where I added the two sinon files before the Jasmine files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sinon/sinon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sinon/sinon-ie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jasmine-core/boot/boot.js"></script>
```

I use Jasmine 1.3.1 and the latest JQuery from here:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
```

Can anybody tell me how to use sinon and Jasmine with the timeout property?